# gtest.h file not found googletest xcode 7.0

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, unit-testing, googletest

I'm trying to setup google testing framework for my c++ project following this [guide](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/XcodeGuide#Set_Up_the_Executable_Run_Environment) in xcode 7.0 I got to the last step Build and Go but after hours of searching online I can't get my test project to run. The compiler does not seem to find the headers it needs. main.cpp:9:10: 'gtest/gtest.h' file not found. The source is:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

#include "calc.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    return 0;
}
```

I also tried
    #include <gtest/gtest.h>
With same result.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes, Xcode cannot find header files in framework. You need additional steps to make it work.

- In **build settings**, complete **Framework Search Paths** with the path to your framework, which is gtest.framework.
- Add the framework path and to **User Header Search Paths**.
- If Xcode cannot find "gtest/internal/gtest-port-arch.h", you can find it in source folder "googletest/googletest/include". Add it to **User Header Search Paths**.

After these steps, gtest should work in Xcode 7.0.

Comment: It's the framework **Headers** path that needs to go in **User Header Search Paths** e.g. ../../googletest/gtest.framework/Headers where ../.. is relative to your xcodeproj

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I got it to work:

Steps:

1. Download the source code `$ svn checkout http://googletest.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ googletest-read-only`
2. `cd` to the folder 'make' in the downloaded source code folder
3. run `$ make gtest.a gtest_main.a`
4. manually copy the two static library files to /usr/local/lib and copy the header file dir 'include/gtest' to /usr/local/include.
5. Add Header Search Path (/usr/local/include) and Library Search Path (/usr/local/lib) to your xcode’s project setting
6. Add linker flag agains gtest. In target setting under "Other Linker Flags". Add /usr/local/lib/gtest.a

   ```
   // main.cpp
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include "gtest/gtest.h"
   #include "calc.hpp" // has function int addition(int,int);
   TEST(MyFirstTest, TestAddition) {
           EXPECT_EQ(3, addition(1, 2));
   }
   GTEST_API_ int main(int argc, char **argv) {
           printf("Running main() from gtest_main.cc\n");
           testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
           return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
   }
   ```

Comment: broken link to article

Comment: @mortond Thanks. I removed the broken link to the article. The article does not exist anymore so no use keeping it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the contents of your DerrivedData folder, and re-building.

[image]