# Setting up google test on Xcode 7.2.1

Tags: c++, xcode, unit-testing, googletest

I'm new to Xcode and Google Test and I want to set up the unit testing environment for C++ using Google Test. I'm getting the typical #include "gtest/gtest.h" file not found error, when I'm building my tests module.

Details for google test:
I followed the tutorial here : http://bitrage.de/wp/google-test-with-xcode-6-and-c11/

Also, I followed the steps on this link [gtest.h file not found googletest xcode 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797023/gtest-h-file-not-found-googletest-xcode-7-0), but that too didn't solve my problem.

I have added the path to the built gtest.framework to my User Header Paths under the Tests module of the project. I have also added the path to the framework under User Framework paths of Xcode project-> Build Settings under the Tests module.

I have linked the binary with framework under the Build Phases for Tests as well. Also, I found out that the header file was under a folder named Headers inside the framework. But #include "Headers/gtest.h" doesn't work as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get this working? and also your link is broken.

Comment: No it did not work. I just transferred to an Ubuntu system and used apt-get to install google test. I cannot find the bitrage.de link anymore.

Comment: I got this working myself afterwards. I will post an answer if it helps.

Comment: @davd please post answer