# Cannot Find User Header Search Paths in Xcode UI

Tags: c++, xcode, googletest

**Context**

I am trying to integrate gtest into Xcode, but Xcode isn't properly linked to the gtest header files. (I can compile/execute the project by running g++ from command line, but not in Xcode)

I am not able to compile in XCode because the following import causes a compile error:
`#include <gtest/gtest.h> 'gtest/gtest.h' file not found`

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797023/gtest-h-file-not-found-googletest-xcode-7-0), and several others, the recommendation is to "Add the framework path and to User Header Search Paths."

However, in my Xcode 13 project, I don't see User Header Search Paths in the Build settings >> Search Paths.  Any idea how to enable it or if there is an alternate property I need to set?

[Photo of my IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpDai.png)

Comment: Click on All instead of Basic.